# requireAudience with multiple valid audiences

Tags: jjwt

I have been working back-end JWT validation and I've been using the JJWT library.

When building the JwtsParser we can call

```
.requireAudience("audience")
```

And this will attempt to match the audience claim in the JWT token and verify it or not depending on the result.

I have a situation where I have multiple audiences (two different front-ends) and I am trying to match the audience to either front-end 1 or front-end 2. However, when I add

```
.requireAudience("FE1")
.requireAudience("FE2")
```

it attempts to match both of those values.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality with the library or should I just write my own audience verify method?

Answer (score 0):

try following changes:

```
public boolean verifyAudience(String jwt, String requiredAudience) {
    JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(yourSigningKey);

    try {
        Claims claims = jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
        List<String> audienceList = claims.getAudience();
        return audienceList.contains(requiredAudience);
    } catch (JwtException e) {
        // Handle JWT verification error
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage:
if (verifyAudience(yourJwt, "FE1") || verifyAudience(yourJwt, "FE2")) {
    // JWT contains either "FE1" or "FE2"
}
```

and then:

```
{
    "aud": ["FE1", "FE2"],
    // other claims
}
```

Comment: I am very well aware that I could have done something like this, what I am asking is if if there is a way within the library to achieve my desired functionality.